# Is it possible to send two different internet connection using same media converter?

Tags: lan, isp, broadband

I have a broadband internet connection that ISP provided me with one media converter. Then the connection is divided into two with a lan switch to provide connection to my neighbour. Is it possible to have two connections with two distinct username and password through one media converter. I just want to be sure whether my ISP is cheating me.

Comment: What do you consider to be a "media converter"?

Comment: Why would whether or not there are two distinct usernames and passwords determine whether or not your ISP is cheating you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's completely possible to provide two logical connections this way. The separation could be done using multiple PPPoE sessions, or using 802.1X and VLANs, and both methods are quite doable with a regular managed switch if the ISP wants to do it that way.

---

The main limit is speed, because a single physical link is still a single physical link. For example, if the media converter gets a 1 Gbps link from the ISP, then it has to share the same link between *both* of your networks – it cannot magically provide 1 Gbps to *each* user.

Of course that's not really a problem if your plans are much lower than that. Let's say you both pay for 100 Mbps plans – in that case, the combined total is still well within capacity of the 1 Gbps media converter and sharing a physical link doesn't make any difference.

---

> I just want to be sure whether my ISP is cheating me.

Your contract with the ISP should list what services they are expected to provide (e.g. bandwidth, latency, reliability). Most of those are something you can easily test.